# Recurly Parse XML

Tags: python, python-2.7, recurly

I've been playing with the Recurly Python library (https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-python) but I can't seem to find a simple way to parse the XML response from their API. Does anyone see a part of this library dedicated to parsing XML strings? I'm worried about building a custom parser and then the XML format changes.

I did a simple http request asking for Transactions and I got back an XML string like what is pasted below, but I don't see anything in their library to turn this into some type of parsed object that I can easily mold into a dataframe

```
  <account href="https://your-subdomain.recurly.com/v2/accounts/1"/>
  <invoice href="https://your-subdomain.recurly.com/v2/invoices/1006"/>
  <subscriptions href="https://your-subdomain.recurly.com/v2/transactions/37bff9ddc1e468a59f6fef417cb32281/subscriptions"/>
  <original_transaction href="https://your-subdomain.recurly.com/v2/transactions/37bfef7b3873aed2af2a3d4d35878e5f"/>
  <uuid>37bff9ddc1e468a59f6fef417cb32281</uuid>
  <action>refund</action>
  <amount_in_cents type="integer">870</amount_in_cents>
  <tax_in_cents type="integer">70</tax_in_cents>
  <currency>EUR</currency>
  <status>success</status>
  <payment_method>credit_card</payment_method>
  <reference>1171163</reference>
  <source>subscription</source>
  <recurring type="boolean">false</recurring>
  <test type="boolean">true</test>
  <voidable type="boolean">true</voidable>
  <refundable type="boolean">false</refundable>
  <ip_address nil="nil"/>
  <cvv_result code="" nil="nil"/>
  <avs_result code="D">Street address and postal code match.</avs_result>
  <avs_result_street nil="nil"/>
  <avs_result_postal nil="nil"/>
  <created_at type="datetime">2016-08-03T16:13:44Z</created_at>
  <updated_at type="datetime">2016-08-03T16:13:44Z</updated_at>
  <details>
    <account>
      <account_code>1</account_code>
      <first_name>Verena</first_name>
      <last_name>Example</last_name>
      <company>Recurly Inc</company>
      <email>verena@example.com</email>
      <billing_info type="credit_card">
        <first_name>Verena</first_name>
        <last_name>Example</last_name>
        <address1>123 Main St.</address1>
        <address2 nil="nil"/>
        <city>San Francisco</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>94105</zip>
        <country>US</country>
        <phone nil="nil"/>
        <vat_number nil="nil"/>
        <card_type>Visa</card_type>
        <year type="integer">2019</year>
        <month type="integer">12</month>
        <first_six>411111</first_six>
        <last_four>1111</last_four>
      </billing_info>
    </account>
  </details>
  <a name="refund" href="https://your-subdomain.recurly.com/v2/transactions/37bff9ddc1e468a59f6fef417cb32281" method="delete"/>
</transaction>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried, and what specific problem(s) you had with it?

Comment: Did you get something like that [recurly.com/docs - transaction-object](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/transaction-object)? If yes insert this to your question.

Comment: great point, adding